# How to prevent caching of a page in a particular IIS web application and in that application only, in Microsoft Edge (Chromium)

Tags: iis, web-config, clickonce, browser-cache, microsoft-edge-chromium

Our default website in IIS has a folder in it that houses a web-application. There are several applications and we want to limit the effect to only the one:

```
     >   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo
```

There are folders beneath \foo, each of which has an HTML page of the same name:

```
       > foo
           sis
              publish.htm
           boom
              publish.htm
           bah
              publish.htm
```

These `publish.htm` files will be edited from time to time.  **We want to prevent them from being cached in Microsoft Edge.**  They are ClickOnce files and only Edge v92 or later will be used to open them.

Could this `web.config`  be  placed in each of the child folders, `sis`, `boom`, and `bah`? Is there a way of putting it in folder `foo` and editing the **path** so it includes *any path* that leads to *any* file called `publish.htm`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="publish.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try placing web.config in foo directory and giving relative path to publish.html files? You will require seperate entry for each relative publish.html file path.

Comment: @PankajKapare: Would there be multiple paths, separated by commas?  There is a publish.htm in each of those three sub-folders.

Comment: Multiple location tags. One for each path.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that could be done!

Comment: @Tim Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @samwu: testing now.

Comment: Running into a problem where the page does not load if I have multiple location elements in the parent folder's web.config, using the subfolder-name as the path, and the subfolders have a web.config also, with a single location element using the file-name as the path.  Decided to eliminate the web.config from the parent folder.